# Periodic slowdown performance in ServiceStack

Tags: c#, servicestack

We have a web service using ServiceStack (v3.9.60) that is currently gets an average (per New Relic monitoring) of 600 requests per minute (load balanced with two Windows 2008 web servers.)

The actual time spend in the coded request Service (including Request Filter) takes about an average of 5ms (From what we see from recorded log4net logs.) It is offloading the request to an ActiveMQ endpoint and automatic have ServiceStack generate a 204 (Return204NoContentForEmptyResponse enabled with "public void Post(request)")

On top of that we have:

```
PreRequestFilters.Insert(0, (httpReq, httpRes) =>
{
    httpReq.UseBufferedStream = true;
});
```

since we use the raw body to validate a salted hash value (passed as a custom header) during a Request Filter for approval reasons that it comes from a correct source.

Overall we see in New Relic that the whole web service call takes an average around 700ms, which is a lot compared to the 5ms it actually takes to perform the coded process. So when we looked deeper in the data New Relic reports we saw some requests periodically take quite some time (10-150 seconds per request.) Drilling down in the reporting of New Relic we see that Applying the Pre-Request Filter takes time (see image below.) We were wondering why this could be the case and if it was related to the buffered stream on the Http Request object and what possibly could be done to correct this?

[image]

**EDIT**

Have been playing around with this some and still haven't found an answer.

Things done:

1. Moved the Virtual Folder out from a sub-folder location of the actual site folder (there are about 11 other Web Services located under this site)
2. Assigned this Web Service to use its own Application Pool so it is not shared with the main site and other Web Services under the site
3. Added the requirement to Web.Config for usage of Server GC as Phil suggested
4. Disabled the pre-request filter that turned on the usage of buffered stream (and bypass the code that used the RawBody)
5. Added more instrumentation to New Relic for a better drill-down (see image below)

I'm starting to wonder if this is a Windows Server/IIS limitation due to load. But would like to hear from someone that is more familiar with such.

[image]

Comment: Do you have server GC enabled? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc165011%28v=office.11%29.aspx

Comment: Server GC is not enabled. It is something to look into. But it seems to be related to getting the actual request. We disabled the buffered stream (and let the validation code get bypassed since RawBody isn't available then) and the slowdown shifted away from EndpointHost.ApplyPreRequestFilters() to RestHandler.GetRequest() - Additional info on the request. We receive them as JSON objects

Comment: Puzzling. We saw a similar behaviour in a WCF server app some time ago (though not quite to the 10-150 second extent) and it was also seemingly immune to performance analysis. The problem went away when we switched to Server GC.

Comment: @PhilDegenhardt - Did you have to assign Server GC to all the existing web services or just that one WCF app? We got quite a few web services on those servers and windows services written in C#

Comment: It is done for each host (app domain). All our services were WAS hosted in IIS so it was a couple of lines in a single web.config for us.

Comment: Is the InputStream really large for any of the requests? If I correctly  understand the 'flow' of where your issues are occurring, it seems the initial read of HttpRequest.InputStream could be the issue. Not sure how to tweak/improve the read performance of it, though.

Comment: @paaschpa - We aren't getting big payloads at all for this web service. I would say in average no more then 400 bytes. Some might sneak up to about 3-4KB.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee787088.aspx P.S. Defaults to background GC